# STS Role Trust relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I have defined a trust relationship in destination account using

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a condition to allow only a specific user to have access to this account when using federations (STS). So I've modified the trust relationship as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER]:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:user-name": "[USER-NAME-FROM-SOURCE-ACCOUNT]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this condition is not getting evaluated. Is `aws:user-name` right in this case for verifying this condition?

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually specify a specific user in the principal field if you specify the user arn, e.g.:

```
"Principal": { 
  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/<username>" 
},
```